# ng-click inside a modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

Form displays properly in a modal window, but the ng-click doesn't seem to have any effect when clicked to display the angular datepicker inside the modal.

Should the   ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'startOpen', event)"   syntax be different when in a modal? It works perfectly when the form is displayed on a webpage (not in a modal).

Solutions I found on stackoverflow didn't work.

See code below or plunker version: http://plnkr.co/nXJ0SKzDemrhvgWyfue5

html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalEventContent.html">
<div class="modal-body" style="height:600px;">
<table class="table table-bordered">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Starts at</th>
    <th>Ends at</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.event.title"></td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="vm.event.type" class="form-control">
        <option value="important">Important</option>
        <option value="warning">Warning</option>
        <option value="info">Info</option>
        <option value="inverse">Inverse</option>
        <option value="success">Success</option>
        <option value="special">Special</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly datepicker-popup="medium" ng-model="vm.event.startsAt" is-open="vm.event.startOpen" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'startOpen', vm.event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
      </p>
      <timepicker ng-model="vm.event.startsAt" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly datepicker-popup="medium" ng-model="vm.event.endsAt" is-open="vm.event.endOpen" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'endOpen', vm.event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
      </p>
      <timepicker ng-model="vm.event.endsAt" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
    </td>

</tbody>

</table>
</div>
</script>
```

sample of code in my demo.js

```
function showEventModal(action, event) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalEventContent.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.action = action;
      vm.event = event;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}  


vm.eventEdited = function(event) {

 $http.get('/api/events/' + event.eventid).success(function(eventsuccess){
 showEventModal('Edited', event);

}).error(function(err){
   /* do something with errors */
});
  //console.log("eventEdited");
};

vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  vm.event[field] = !vm.event[field];
};
```

*** Update ***

showEventModal function was updated as per @RomanKoliada suggestion to add vm.toggle function inside the controller, but problem wasn't solved :

```
function showEventModal(action, event) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalEventContent.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.action = action;
      vm.event = event;

      vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            event[field] = !event[field];
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}
```

*** Final Update (solution) ***

Thanks to @RomanKoliada, a solution was found. Code above has been updated with the solution below

In demo.js, this line was changed from:

```
event[field] = !event[field];
```

to

```
vm.event[field] = !vm.event[field];
```

In html, is-open was changed from:

```
is-open="event.startOpen"
```

to

```
is-open="vm.event.startOpen"
```

Comment: Your plunker is broken.

Comment: There's no datetime displayed, but tried to recreate the problem: datepicker not displaying in modal

Comment: Yeah, it's very broken. I think you haven't tested it. There are dependency injection issues to deal with first or nothing will work correctly. The next thing to fix is making sure you're fully using controllerAs syntax. `event.startOpen = true` is probably not what you need.

Comment: I see. i'm a bit lost with angular, but I'll try to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Plunker updated. Problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't have proper functions in:

```
controller: function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.action = action;
  vm.event = event;
},
```

You should add inside that controller:

```
 controller: function() {
     var vm = this;
     vm.toggle=function($event, 'endOpen', event){...};
     ...
 },
```

For opening datepicker try to change:

```
is-open="vm.event.startOpen"
```

and in toggle function:

```
 vm.event[field] = !vm.event[field];
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't show all my code in the sample (demo.js above), but I just did an edit to add the function that go with the vm.toggle. I think I might have something missing in that function for the ng-click to work and display the datepicker in my modal.

Comment: That'a what i'm talking about! Inside modal you can access only functions that defined inside: $modal.open({ controller: function() {...}, ... });

Comment: Thanks for you help, I tested it and when I click the datepicker, the vm.toggle function gets called with the proper values, but unfortunately the datepicker does not appear. I feel I'm getting closer though

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your flag variable must be in a scope too.

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius. It worked after adding  vm.  to is-open="vm.event.startOpen" like you suggested. Thanks so much! you rock!